# Overriding a pure virtual function from templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have searched stack overflow but haven't found something that exactly answers my question.  I have an interface class which contains only pure virtual functions which I would like to be implemented by classes which derive from this class.

I have an interface that I will call **BaseInterface** which defines functions that I would like to be overridden in all classes which derive from this interface.  In this example, say there is only one pure virtual function called *toImplement*.  I create a class called **Base** which inherits from **BaseInterface** and adds some functionality to the inherited pure virtual functions.  Base is still an abstract class since it does not implement the functions in **BaseInterface**.

I have several classes which derive from **Base** which all benefit from the common functionality of **Base** but specify what happens when *toImplement* is run on their instances.  These classes should all be concrete and satisfy all the requirements set by **BaseInterface**. Below I define one of these classes called **Derived**.

All of this works fine when BaseInterface and Base are not templated.  The code compiles and runs fine without defining (1.) or implementing (2.) *toImplement* in **Base**.

However I would like *toImplement* to work with different types.  From what I understand it is fine to have pure virtual functions in a templated class.  I template **BaseInterface** and **Base** on some type T.  When I don't define *toImplement* in **Base** (1.), I cannot compile since Base doesn't know which *toImplement* to use in *tryUsingImplemented*.  If I now add the definition to **Base**, the code pre-compiles but the linker cannot find the implementation of Base::toImplement.  Finally, if I both define and implement *toImplement* in **Base** (1. and 2.), the code compiles.

I don't like this because I have a dummy implementation of *toImplement* in Base and I never want this implementation to be run.  Additionally, because **Base** implements *toImplement*, **Derived** is no longer required to implement it.  This makes **BaseInterface** useless in my eyes.

Can sombody enlighten me on how to enforce the implementation of *toImplement* in **Derived**, without having to implement it in **Base** first if that is at all possible?

```
template <typename T>
class BaseInterface {
   virtual void toImplement(T & t) = 0;
};


template <typename T>
class Base : public BaseInterface<T> {
bool m_useImplemented;

public:
   explicit Base(bool useImplemented) : m_usedImplemented(useImplemented) {}

   void tryUsingImplemented(T & t) {
      if (m_useImplemented)
         toImplement(t);
   }  

protected:
   // 1: Defining toImplement pure virtual function in Base
   virtual void toImplement(T & t);
};

// 2. Implementing a version of toImplement in Base which does nothing
template <typename T>
inline void Base<T>::toImplement(T & t) {
   // do nothing
}

class Derived : public Base<int> {
public:
   explicit Derived(bool useImplemented) : Base<int>(useImplemented) {}

protected:
   // 3. implementing toImplement in Derived 
   void toImplement(T & t) {
      std::cout << "Doing stuff for Derived" << std::endl;
   }  

};
```

Comment: You can provide definitions for pure virtual functions. If you don't want derived classes to perform a non-virtual call to `Base::toImplement` then make it a private function.

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem as much as possible and I indeed forgot to define BaseInterface<T>::toImplement as protected.  It was in the original code so the problem is not one of access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, it would be helpful if you provided the compiler error message.

However, in this case I know. There are two errors in your code:

1. `toImplement` is private in `BaseInterface`.
2. The lookup in `tryUsingImplemented` will not look in the base class. You're facing the [lookup in dependent bases](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/) problem. To fix it, write `this->toImplement(t)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I believe the problem was indeed lookup in dependent bases.  I removed definitions and implementations of pure virtuals in Base and replaced their calls with: this->toImplement and the compiler now knows to use the BaseInterface<T>::toImplement

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `toImplement` as `protected` in `BaseInterface` if you intend to call it from a derived class. I have removed all the overriding methods from the derived classes and replaced the parameter type of `Derived::toImplement` with `int`, and it compiles fine. The latter is necessary because `Derived` is not a template, so you need to use the template parameter passed to `Base`.

```
  #include <iostream>

  template <typename T>
  class BaseInterface {
  protected:
     virtual void toImplement(T & t) = 0;
  };


  template <typename T>
  class Base : public BaseInterface<T> {
  bool m_useImplemented;

  public:
     explicit Base(bool useImplemented) : m_useImplemented(useImplemented) {}

     void tryUsingImplemented(T & t) {
        if (m_useImplemented)
           toImplement(t);
     }  
  };

  class Derived : public Base<int> {
  public:
     explicit Derived(bool useImplemented) : Base<int>(useImplemented) {}

  protected:
     // 3. implementing toImplement in Derived 
     void toImplement(int & t) {
        std::cout << "Doing stuff for Derived" << std::endl;
     }  

  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I forgot to add the protected keyword to BaseInterface but it is in my original code so that wasn't the problem.  The problem was in calling toImplement in Base in which the compiler didn't know that toImplement dependend on template T.  This is fixed by using this->toImplement

Comment: Hmm, it compiled without problems for me with clang. But still, good to know about that issue.